# How can I use setInterval function for each custom control objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, sapui5

I created a custom control and created two objects of it in [sapui5](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/c7c26285a53b461cbecb3da2c51a2f64.html). in my customControl.js in onAfterRendering function I wrote a setInterval code which will update the value property of custom control periodically. I create my custom controls in my view :

```
<controls:customControl
    id="customID1"
    value="50"/>
<controls:customControl
    id="customID2"
    value="70"/>
```

Here is my control :

```
CustomControl.prototype.onAfterRendering = function()
{
    setInterval(this.updateControl(this), 500);
}
```

But it seems when this method works, it updates all custom control objects with same value. So when I update the value property of first control as 52 and the value property of second control as 72. But I only can see 72 value for both controls.

I also tried to use [sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger.html) method in my onAftering method like below:

```
var iT = new sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger(500);
iT.addListener(this.updateControl, this);
```

but this doesn't work and I last tried to use closure but it doesn't work again.

```
(function(self){   
    var iT = new sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger(500);
    iT.addListener(self.updateGauge, self);
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

@melomg, you should post some more details, including you custom control and the implementation of your updateControl function. I can only guess what's going wrong, anyway... Here is a working example (see code below) which runs just fine. Check the comments in the code for more information, especially because of the re-rendering loop issue that you might have (I can only guess this).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
                xmlns:nabisoft="nabisoft">

                <!-- use our custom control, see below -->
                <nabisoft:CustomControl id="one" value="1" interval="500"/>
                <nabisoft:CustomControl id="two" value="90000" interval="1000"/>

            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Custom Control ###              
                jQuery.sap.declare("nabisoft.CustomControl");
                sap.ui.core.Control.extend("nabisoft.CustomControl", {
                    metadata : {
                        properties : {
                          value : {type : "int"},
                          interval : {type : "int", default:500}
                        },
                        aggregations : {},
                        associations: {},
                        events : {}
                    },

                    init : function(){},
                    
                    onAfterRendering: function (){
                      setInterval(this.updateControl.bind(this), this.getInterval());
                    },
                    
                    updateControl : function () { 
                      var iOldValue = this.getValue();
                      var iNewValue = iOldValue + 1;
                      
                      // don't do this, because this will lead to a rerendering loop!!!
                      //this.setValue( iNewValue );
                      
                      //instead do this here:
                      this.setProperty("value", iNewValue,  true /*supress rerendering*/);
                      this.$().find("span").text(iNewValue);
                      
                    },

                    renderer : {
                        render : function(oRm, oControl) {
                            oRm.write("<div");
                            oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
                            oRm.addClass("nsCustomControl");
                            oRm.writeClasses();
                            oRm.write(">");
                            oRm.write("<div>" + oControl.getId() +" : <span>" + oControl.getValue() + "</span></div>");
                            oRm.write("</div>");
                        }
                    }
                });

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```